# When does "$viewValue" become "NOT undefined"?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my example to count value length in the input text:

```js
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function ($event, form) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    
    alert(form.myinput.$viewValue.length)
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" ng-model="myForm" name="myForm" novalidate ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-model="myinput" name="myinput" />
  <a href="#" ng-click="submit($event, myForm)">Submit</a>
</form>
```

The problem: If the value in the input is null or empty (the input contained nothing before), it would throw this error when clicking on `submit`:

> **TypeError**: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at a.$$childScopeClass.$$childScopeClass.$scope.submit

Then, I've tried to type something in the input, delete it and click on `submit` again. It should work.

My question: for `input[type=text]`, is there nothing like `default value` with property `$viewValue`?

I mean: if the value is null or empty, `form.myinput.$viewValue` should be `''`. So, the length must be `0`.

Comment: This is a very old way to program with angular, and a very old build of angular.  Angular is a very active framework that is kept quite up to date;  there is no reason to use a release of angular from September, 2014 in a new code sample.

Comment: @Claies Thanks! I would change it. May you provide me some link that contains the morden way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

It will check first for `null` and `empty` value of the text box and then perform operation according to that.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.submit = function () {
    if($scope.myinput != null && $scope.myinput.length > 0) {
    alert($scope.myinput.length);
      } else {
        alert("Please enter the text");
        }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" novalidate ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-model="myinput" name="myinput" />
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access it via the scope. $scope.form.myinput.$viewValue.length

That being said I do not believe that controllers should know about form as forms are a view concept. Anything to do with the form variable should not make their way into your controllers. I am a big fan of not passing the $scope into your controllers at all and using the controller as syntax.

Comment: `$scope.form.myinput.$viewValue.length` inside or outside `submit()` function, please?

Comment: Don't access it like that. You have a binding with ng-model to the scope so access it with $scope.myinput

Comment: Please read about controller as syntax. As you are new to Angular this is a very Angular 1.2 way of doing things. Controller as syntax was introduced in 1.3 and discourages the injection of $scope into your controllers.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! May you copy my example and edit it via using `$scope`?

Comment: See my solution below to do it without injecting $scope

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. This will only work with Angular 1.3 or greater as 1.2 doesn't support controller as.

```js
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.submit = function () {
    alert(vm.myinput);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" novalidate ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
  <input ng-model="vm.myinput" name="myinput" />
  <button ng-click="vm.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```